# Serverless framework: Serverless Error Function not found:

Tags: node.js, serverless-framework

I'm getting started with nodejs and the serverless framwork.

My handler.js contains:

```
'use strict';
var index = require('./index.js');

module.exports.hello = async event => {
  var res = await index.main();

  console.log('hello');
  console.log(res);

  console.log('IN HANDLER');
  return {
    statusCode: 200,
    body: JSON.stringify(
      {
        message: 'main function executed!',
        input: event,
      },
      null,
      2
    ),
  };


};
```

My serverless.yml contains:

```
# You can pin your service to only deploy with a specific Serverless version
# Check out our docs for more details
# frameworkVersion: "=X.X.X"

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs12.x
  region: us-east-1
  # here we put the layers we want to use
  layers:
    # Google Chrome for AWS Lambda as a layer
    # Make sure you use the latest version depending on the region
    # https://github.com/shelfio/chrome-aws-lambda-layer
    # - arn:us-east-1:arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:764866452798:layer:chrome-aws-lambda:10
    - arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:764866452798:layer:chrome-aws-lambda:10
  # function parameters

# you can add packaging information here
#package:
#  include:
#    - include-me.js
#    - include-me-dir/**
#  exclude:
#    - exclude-me.js
#    - exclude-me-dir/**

functions:
  hello:
    handler: handler.hello
  # main:
    # handler: handler.main
#    The following are a few example events you can configure
#    NOTE: Please make sure to change your handler code to work with those events
#    Check the event documentation for details
    events:
     - http:
         path: hello/get
         method: get
```

my index.js:

```
async function main(event, context, callback) {
  const chromium = require('chrome-aws-lambda');
  const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
  const os = require('os');
  const CREDS = require('./.creds');

  // exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {
  let result = null;
  let browser = null;

    try {
      browser = await chromium.puppeteer.launch({
        args: chromium.args,
        defaultViewport: chromium.defaultViewport,
        executablePath: await chromium.executablePath,
        headless: chromium.headless,
        ignoreHTTPSErrors: true,
      })
    } 
      catch {
      console.log('browser failed')
    };



  var page = await browser.newPage();

   ........



  // })().catch(e => { console.error(e) });
};

main().catch(e => { console.error(e) });

module.exports.main = main;
```

When I run :

```
$ sls invoke -f hello

 Serverless Error ---------------------------------------

 Function not found: arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:155754363046:function:sellthelandnow-dev-hello
```

The error is in the title. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What's `sellthelandnow-dev-hello` ? I don't se it anywhere in the code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me explain here. Serverless framework can invoke(run) lambda in two ways(locally and in cloud-AWS). 
It seems you are trying to invoke lambda in AWS. (arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:155754363046:function:sellthelandnow-dev-hello) Basically this arn does not exist in your AWS-155754363046 account. you need to use

```
serverless deploy
```

to deploy lamdba to aws env.If you just want to test locally, the command is

```
serverless invoke local --function functionName
```

So I will suggest in case you want to invoke lambda in the cloud.You need to first deploy it Or you use invoke local.

Thanks,

Ashish

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4):

In my specific case i had this error code when **i deleted the deployed lambda function** in the AWS Management Console **but did not delete the Application Stack** and tried to **deploy the lambda function again** using

```sh
serverless deploy
```

### You have to delete the Application stack and also make sure to delete IAM Execution Role for your lambda.

---

#### Additional Information

I didn't have to delete the s3 bucket - it was reused.

You can find your application stack in the AWS Management Console

- `AWS Management Console` → `Lambda` → `Applications`

And delete

- `AWS Management Console` → `CloudFormation` → `Stacks`
- If the deletion fails u might be prompted to keep associated resources (IAM Role and s3 Bucket)
- choose to keep the resources and delete them afterwards manually

### Error Message

> An error occurred: [functionName]LambdaFunction - Resource handler returned message: "Lambda function [application stack name]-[application stage]-[lambda function name] could not be found" (RequestToken: 01010011-0111-0011-1100-001100110011, HandlerErrorCode: NotFound).

Comment: Deleting CloudFormation stacks worked for me. I have to deleted twice though because the first time always fails. Also, I don't have to delete IAM role because I could find any associated with the lambda.